# how to upload a file from android app to google app engine using GAE

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I have a JSP file where the form field will uploads a file to Google app engine, the below code shows it,

```
 <form name="myform" id="myform" action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/adminupload",UploadOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageBucketName("sampleapp")) %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

as i wrote this program with jsp and servlet i need to provide the same process in android app. If my GAE path is say like this http://sampleapp.appspot.com/Upload.jsp how can i provide this link in the form action property of an android app. As i don't have idea about android app. Kindly suggest me what to provide in android app form property so that from the app a file can be uploaded.

Kindly tell me whether it is possible in android form to give url path like this,

```
http://sampleapp.appspot.com/uploadservlet
```

so that the android app will upload the file in the GAE sampleapp.appspot.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. Use an [HttpPost object](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) by passing your server URL in the constructor.

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(urlString);
```

**[EDIT]:** Just noticed you used multipart entries. I'd suggest you do something of the sort explained [in this tutorial](http://evgeny-goldin.com/blog/uploading-files-multipart-post-apache/).

When you pass the url as a parameter you're telling Java the destination for your request. So your request must then contain your file data (written in any way you wish [DataOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) or any other way) and then you must [execute it using an HttpClient object](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html).

Further, from the [GAE pages on JSP](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingjsps) you can see that every new `<form action="/handleName" method="methodName">` you add will result in:

> .. a new URL, /handleName, to be handled by a new servlet class...

Comment: So if i pass the url http://sampleapp.appspot.com/uploadservlet in urlString as you mentioned will the android app uploads the file to GAE ?

Comment: fine as am using blob store service in form action like this, `action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/adminupload",UploadOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageBucketName("sampleapp")) %>"`  can i use the http://sampleapp.appspot.com/adminupload in the `createuploadUrl` function of the form

Comment: Google app engine uses your server file to understand what handles perform what actions. So if you've created the /adminupload handle and performed your above action there, then yes you can use that handle in the urlString.

Comment: Thats my doubt whether i can give `action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("** http://sampleapp.appspot.com/adminupload **",UploadOptions.Builder.withGoogle‌​StorageBucketName("sampleapp")) %>"` in android form and you cleared it YES we Can... Thank you so much varevarao..

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry for the ongoing babble then. :D

Comment: Nothing so you gave me a detailed explanation. Thanks a lot :)